# How to use <?choose:?> inside image url function in BI Publisher template

Tags: bi-publisher, jdedwards

I'm totally new at BI Publisher and XML templates. I'm trying to update a template to add the logo for a new company/organization. The same templates will be used for 3 separate branches/organizations within JD Edwards.

I'm having trouble trying to conditionally set the `url` code in the alt text of the dummy image. I think it's because the interpreter can't understand having a `<?choose:?>` tag inside the `url{}` definition? How can I use a choose function to return the proper string to the `url{}` definition?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

**Concatenation:**

Just concatenate the source location of your image with an XML variable that holds the brand name.

```
url:{concat('/folder1/folder2/',BRANCH_NAME_XML_ELEMENT,'_LOGO.JPG')}
```

Assuming your `BRANCH_NAME_XML_ELEMENT` is `WALMART` it will then load the image: `/folder1/folder2/WALMART_LOGO.JPG`

**IF Statements**

Make three different dummy images. Each with their respective URL for the logo. Then put each image within an if/end if statement. Will make things look like hell in the RTF file, but it will functionally work when everything is rendered.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter what I do, the dummy image never gets replaced.  Is there an error log somewhere that might have some messages which can shed light on what's not working?

Comment: Did your DBA grant all the correct permissions for the folder on the server?

Comment: I was able to make it work using three IF statements, so it's not a permissions issue. It does make the template very messy! I think BIP either doesn't like the `choose` statement or the `normalize-space` function I have to use to trim off all of JDE's field padding before comparing the branch code. I don't know which functions can be used where.